# Reading specific fields from a spacific record in Access 2010 from within Excel 2010

Tags: excel, ms-access

I have the following Excel VBA code that worked fine until I converted my Access(2007) database to an Access(2010) database.  I have used some of the new features in Access(2010) to improve my database but now my Excel macro will not run.  I get the following message.

Run-time error 3343 Unreconized database format

I think the fix may be an easy fix but I am not a programmer so I am at a lost.... Thanks in advance for your help
.

```
Sub Get_Hardware()  'Retrieves hardware weights from Access database

'********Note: If program fails to run, in the visual basic editor, under tools, references, you may
'        need to have "Microsoft DAO 3.6 Object Library" downloaded**********

' ******* May also need to register DAO 3.6 if it does not apear in the selectable list by doing the following.
'       1.  Open Window's start menu and select "Run"
'       2.  Paste the following into the run windo and tell it to run it....
'            regsvr32 "c:\program files\common files\microsoft shared\dao\dao360.dll"


Do While Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0))

    DAOCopyFromRecordSet "\\fil-ict-07\s0052491$\Engineering\Mass Properties Database (Access 2010)\Mass Properties Database (2010).accdb", "Hardware", "Part Number", ActiveCell
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select


Loop

End Sub
___________________________________________________________________________________________

Public Sub DAOCopyFromRecordSet(DBFullName As String, TableName As String, _
    FieldName As String, TargetRange As Range)

Dim db As Database, UW, MC, Des, WQ As Recordset
Dim intColIndex As Integer
Dim MatCode As String

    Set TargetRange = TargetRange.Cells(1, 3)
    Set db = OpenDatabase(DBFullName)


    'SQL Query
    Set UW = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT  Std_Parts.UnitWeight FROM Std_Parts WHERE (((Std_Parts.[Part Number]) = '" & _
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0).Value & "'))", dbReadOnly)

    Set MC = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT  Std_Parts.Material_Code FROM Std_Parts WHERE (((Std_Parts.[Part Number]) = '" & _
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0).Value & "'))", dbReadOnly)

    Set Des = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT  Std_Parts.Description FROM Std_Parts WHERE (((Std_Parts.[Part Number]) = '" & _
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0).Value & "'))", dbReadOnly)

    Set WQ = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT  Std_Parts.Qual FROM Std_Parts WHERE (((Std_Parts.[Part Number]) = '" & _
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0).Value & "'))", dbReadOnly)


    ' write recordset
    TargetRange.CopyFromRecordset UW
    Set TargetRange = TargetRange.Cells(1, 0)
    TargetRange.CopyFromRecordset Des
    Set TargetRange = TargetRange.Cells(1, 3)
    TargetRange.CopyFromRecordset MC
    Set TargetRange = TargetRange.Cells(1, 22)
    TargetRange.CopyFromRecordset WQ

    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 6).Select

    ActiveCell.Formula = "=RC[-4]*RC[-1]"
GoOn:
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, -6).Select


    Set UW = Nothing
    Set MC = Nothing
    Set Des = Nothing
    Set WQ = Nothing
    db.Close


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a reference to `Microsoft Office 12.0 Access Database Engine Object Library`, not the old DAO library.

Comment: Will the DAO commands work if I referance the Microsoft Office 12.0 Access Database Engine Object Library?

Comment: They should do, Microsoft Office 12.0 Access Database Engine Object is the latest version of the DAO library. Your code worked for me when I added this reference.